# How to get-latest a lot of files reliably in source control explorer

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I have a repository in TFS/Azure DevOps with ~100.000 files in it. Each time i have to set up a new machine, i'm running into problems.

In VS, i connect to the workspace and do a "map&get". This allways fails. Quite a lot of files are downloaded, but far from all. Sometimes VS does show an error message, sometimes it doesn't. I *do* get an email from devops which basically states, that the operation was "delayed" because limits have been reached. It points to the Usage stats where i can see, that indeed, requests for the FileDownloadHandler have been delayed.

When looking at the docs to this, they state, that, basically, things get "delayed", incase a user is using more than 200 times the amount of resources than he normally does.

Which, of course, is true in this case: the "user" is trying to download all the files and this is most certainly more than 200x the amount of commands when working normally.

However, VS (2015) doesn't seem to realize that things have gone wrong. Because quite a lot of files are missing on the local machine at the end of the operation. (It doesn't wait itself and begins a new download operation after some time.) So i do what the docs say and wait for 5 more minutes and do a "get-latest". This fails totally, because VS thinks "all files are up to date".

[I'm using 2015, because i don't actually want to use vs on that machine. i am using the tfs command line tools and these can only be installed when vs 2015 has previously been installed.]

Also, a "get specific/overwrite" doesn't work, becasue this end up with the same resource  limit problem that created the problem in the first place.

So i basically end up using a "map&get", folloed by waiting a couple if minutes, followed by a "compare", again waiting, followed by a "reconcile" on the result set from the "compare".

Which isn't a nice workflow.

So what is one supposed to do, when you have a large number of files in source control?

Comment: Do you use local workspace or server workspace?

Comment: I am using a server workspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, according to this:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/how-to-get-latest-a-lot-of-files-reliably-in-sourc/1488274

Basically, a repository with >= 100.000 files or >= 10 GB in size is "too big" for Azure DevOps. Doesn't matter if TFS or Git is used.